# Regular expression for valid US phone number

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to cleanse a data set from erroneous phone number entries. Having trouble making the regular expression for the filter in MySQL.

The structure is the following:
First digit is in 2-9
Second and third digits can be any numeral *except they may not be the same number*
Forth digit is in 2-9
Fifth and sixth digits can be any numeral *except '11'*

I've landed on a few rather elaborate reg expressions which didn't quite work; but I'm sure there is a simplistic approach.

A "valid" number might look like:
2028658680
7137038891

My filter usually misses cases such as:
6778914351
7777777777
6178116678

Note that these numbers are completely made up.

Comment: can you provide samples which match your cases

Comment: Added some fabricated examples

Comment: You can't meet these criteria with a regular expression. Specifically, the part where some characters' requirements rely on others.

Comment: `[2-9](\d)(?!\1)\d[2-9](?!11)\d{2}`

Comment: You are stuck here, because MySQL does not support *backreferences* and thus your second condition cannot be coded with the MySQL regex. Well, it does not support lookarounds either, and that makes it a bit hard to implement the last condition. No way to solve the issue with a MySQL regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but it will be long and ugly. With a more robust regex engine you can do lookaround and even conditional statements, but MySQL doesn't support such things as far as I know.

`^[2-9](?:0[1-9]|1[02-9]|2[013-9]|3[0-24-9]|4[0-35-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[0-57-9]|7[0-689]|8[0-79]|9[0-8])[2-9](?:1[02-9]|[02-9]1|[02-9]{2})[0-9]{4}$`

https://regex101.com/r/qPuS5W/1

Explanation:

`[2-9]` First digit is any number from 2 to 9.

`(?:0[1-9]|1[02-9]|2[013-9]|3[0-24-9]|4[0-35-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[0-57-9]|7[0-689]|8[0-79]|9[0-8])` Non capturing group that contains 10 alternatives starting with each number 0 to 9 followed by any number except that number.

`(?:1[02-9]|[02-9]1|[02-9]{2})` Non capturing group that matches either 1 followed by a number that isn't 1, a number that isn't 1 followed by 1, or two numbers that aren't 1.

`[0-9]{4}` 4 of any number.